Two different ways to calculate the expected value of the commutator $[x,p^2]$
We are given the following commutator expression:
$$
\langle p | [x, p^2] | p \rangle = \langle p | x p^2 - p^2 x | p \rangle
$$
Two possible results are given:

$$
\langle p | [x, p^2] | p \rangle = \langle p | xp^2 | p \rangle - \langle p | p^2x | p \rangle = 0
$$

$$
\langle p | [x, p^2] | p \rangle = 2i \hbar \langle p | p | p \rangle = 2i \hbar p \delta(0)
$$


Which one is correct and why?

This question is similar to: Commutator expectation value in quantum mechanics. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also this.

Neither is correct. Because $|p\rangle$ is not a normalizable state, you can't really compute the expectation value in this state. The correct quantity that you can consider is
$$
\langle p'|[X,P^2]|p\rangle
$$
Let us evaluate this two different ways,
\begin{align}
\langle p'|[X,P^2]|p\rangle &= \langle p'| X P^2 |p\rangle - \langle p'| P^2 X |p\rangle \\
&= p^2 \langle p'| X |p\rangle - p'^2 \langle p'| X  |p\rangle \\
&= ( p^2 - p'^2 ) \langle p'| X |p\rangle \\
&= -i\hbar ( p^2 - p'^2 ) \frac{d}{dp}  \langle p' |p\rangle \\
&= -i\hbar ( p^2 - p'^2 )\frac{d}{dp}  \delta(p-p') \\
&= 2i\hbar p \delta(p-p')
\end{align}
Alternatively,
\begin{align}
\langle p'|[X,P^2]|p\rangle &= 2 i \hbar \langle p'|P|p\rangle \\
&= 2 i \hbar p \langle p'|p\rangle \\
&= 2 i \hbar p \delta(p-p') 
\end{align}
All is well.

Thanks a lot! I have tried to think this way but got stuck by $x\delta'(x)$. I didn't know that it is just $\delta(x)$.

@John  :   $x\delta(x)=0$. Derive it w.r.t. x, so $\delta (x) + x\delta '(x) =0$.
